# creating 1000000000 random numbers and sorting them with Bubble sort C++

Tags: c++

I want to create 1000000000(10 raise to power 9) random numbers then sort then with bubble sort method in C++.... but it doesn't work after 100000 (10 raise to power 5) i am really trying my level best please help me..it does generate but it doesn't sort idk why
Here is my code:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
int main()
{

    std::vector<int> arr(1000000);
    int i,temp,m,k;
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    {
        arr[i]= rand()%1000000;
    }

      for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)
      {
          printf("arr[%d] = %d \n",i,arr[i]);
      }
      for(m=0;m<1000000-1;m++){
   for(k=0;k<1000000-1;k++){
    if(arr[k]>arr[k+1]){
        temp = arr[k];
        arr[k] = arr[k+1];
        arr[k+1] = temp;
    }
    }
    }
    printf("\nThe Sorted Array is : ");
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        printf(" |%d| \t",arr[i]);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile at all. What type do you expect `i` to have?

Comment: @Anonymous guy You declared the variable i as having the type std::vector<int>. So this for loop  for(i=0;i<1000000;i++) is incorrect. At least remove this declaration std::vector<int> (i);

Comment: soo how should i correct it?? please send code

Comment: This doesn't compile, so if it runs as you seem to imply then it must be different code or a weird compiler setup. The starting point needs to be either post the actual code you are running, or give some additional information how you managed to get this to compile. Because as it stands, this isn't in a form where I can even tell you what is happening because as far as I can tell this isn't runnable code.

Comment: When you were testing to determine "it doesn't work after 100000 (10 raise to power 5)", how many changes did you need to make to your code for each trial? Six? Wouldn't it be easier to define a symbolic constant like `constexpr size_t VECTOR_SIZE = 100000;` then replace things like `arr(1000000)` with `arr(VECTOR_SIZE)`? Then there would be only one line of code to change per trial. This is one reason "magic numbers" are bad.

Comment: i am running it...i am using  Code::Blocks 20.03

Comment: This is what I see when I try to run it: https://ideone.com/iqA4KC

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler. I still have no idea what compiler or compiler settings would accept this as valid code.

Comment: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: open this website paste my code in here it run

Comment: That gives the exact same error.

Comment: how is this even possible it is working fine on my side in website AND doesn't work in yours even though it is ONLINE how???

Comment: can u guys please please please please create a code and send it to me that generates 1000000000 random numbers then sort them with bubble sort method

Comment: Ah, you changed the code after I posted my comments. Sorry I didn't. see

Comment: please change this code in any way you want just help me achieve the result i think the int i is issue cause it does generate numbers but it doesn't sort them

Comment: Here is what I think might work https://ideone.com/yaRIUi My guess is that you either update the lengths all at the same time or that you are underestimating how long it will take to loop through the the nested loop takes. It loops through (1000000000-1)*(1000000000-1) times. For the runtime... well not much I can do about that.

Comment: Back of the napkin math, it'll take a good computer about 100,000 years to bubble sort a vector of 1,000,000,000 numbers.  I suggest making sure you've first put on a pot of tea while you wait it out.

Comment: ur code is running but i am waiting to see if it will sort or not

Comment: "... but it doesn't work..."  What does it do when it "doesn't work"?  Are the numbers not sorted?

Comment: The answer to all questions of the form "my program doesn't work please help me":  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: my laptop is core i 5

Comment: and it doesn't work means the next part doesn't start no error nothing it does create 100000000 random numbers but it the sorting part doesn't happen the program doesn't even generate error doesn't end the cursor just blinks there after creating random numbers no error nothing

Comment: @Anonymousguy *"it doesn't work means [..] the cursor just blinks there after creating random numbers"* -- this information (including what I omitted for brevity in the comments) should be in the question. Also, since you have a huge loop right after the last output you see, it might be helpful to include a line to output the current value of `m`  in each of that loop's iterations, perhaps an output line right before the loop over `k`. That should provide insight into where your code gets stuck.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what "it doesn't sort" means. It prints unsorted numbers? Crashes? Takes too long to run?

A few comments, short of handing out working code:

1. I suggest you google bubble sort. After the Nth iteration, at least N number are sorted, and therefore don't have to be compared. This cuts half the run time. Another optimization is to check whether the inner loop swapped any values - the vector is sorted if it hasn't, allowing for early exit.
2. C++ has std::swap to swap variables, in place of using three lines & a temporary variable.
3. You're using cstdio & conio (C style I/O) instead of C++'s iostreams.
4. You're using C style random number generator instead of C++'s Pseudo-random number generation library.
5. The appropriate type to iterate over STL containers is size_t, not int.

Comment: While this is useful information, it does not really address the question of why the code "doesn't work". The only comment that I see potentially changing non-working code to working code is #5, but even that is unlikely to cause a "working" to "not working" break just after 100,000 (a 16-bit `int` would break before that point, and a 32-bit `int` would break orders of magnitude later). The rest of your comments address efficiency and style, not "working".